# Using JQUERY UI Dialog as LOGIN tool in Asp.net(C#) page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to use the JQueryUI Dialog feature as a login form i.e when the user will click the Login link(or button) this dialog box will be displayed which will ask the user to enter his username & pass with the Signin button..after filling the uname & pass when the user will click the Signin button inside the Dialog box, it'll carry out the btnSignin_onClick event..

I dont know whether this is possible or not..this is some mixture of client side + server side events i guess..I searched out the web but it was of no help..If you could give me some help regarding this..

thanx in advance..

Answer (score 1):

yes it's possible...

starts with javascript:

```
$(function () {
    // handle the login button click event
    $('#myButton').click(function (e) {

        // prevents the page do post
        $(e).preventDefault();

        // call your login routine *Assync*
        $.ajax({
            url: 'YOUR_URL_HERE',
            type: 'POST',
            // this will serialize the user and password inputs...
            data: $('#myForm').serialize(), // or usr=root&pwd=123, 
            success: function (data) { /* you are logged! THEN DO SOMETHING! */ },
            error: function (error) { /* something is wrong (maybe your password is wrong)! DO SOMETHING! */ },
            complete: function () { /* ajax login was peform well! now you can redirect or show user's information. */ }
        });
    });
});
```

on asp.net application create a ASHX to handle the login like:

```
[WebMethod]
public bool Login(string usr, string pwd) { /* (...) */ }
```

This is the theory!